# How can I interpolate the value of points placed on a timeline?

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I want to create an interpolated plot of the concentration of 'x' over time at different locations. If possible, I would like to interpolate the points horizontally (i.e. over time) in a way that I get smooth color-changing horizontal lines for each sample.

```
df<-data.frame(Concentration = rnorm(30), Position = rep(c(0, 1), 15), Sample = rep(c("A", "B"), 15), Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-30"), "days"))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Position)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = c(0,1),
              size = 0.3) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = Concentration),
               interpolate = T) +
    xlab("Day")+
    ylab("Sample")
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.
Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what `ggforce::geom_link` was made for.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(Concentration = rnorm(30), Position = rep(c(0, 1), 15), Sample = rep(c("A", "B"), 15), Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-30"), "days"))

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Position)) +
  geom_link2(aes(group = Position, color = Concentration), size = 10) +
  labs(x = "Day", y = "Sample")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: P.S. if you use sample functions such as `rnorm`, always best to `set.seed`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but here is one possible solution to what I think you are asking.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <-
  data.frame(Concentration = rnorm(30),
             Sample = rep(c("A", "B"), 15),
             Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 
                             as.Date("2020-01-30"), "days"))

interpolated_df <- 
  df %>% 
  arrange(Sample) %>% 
  complete(Sample, Date) %>% 
  ## interpolated is average of value right before and right after
  mutate(Interpolations = (lead(Concentration) + 
                       lag(Concentration))/2 ) %>% 
  mutate(Final = coalesce(Concentration, Interpolations)) 
  
## plot
interpolated_df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Sample)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Final)) +
  xlab("Day")+
  ylab("Sample")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>